# CMD Batch file to toggle desktop icon from icon1 to icon2 and vis versa, needs 2 double clicks?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I am writing a batch file that uses a VBScript function to toggle a desktop icon between icon1.ico and icon2.ico. Essentially I would like to show the user the state of the program, whether my app is in mode_On or mode_Off.

The problem is that the shortcut "mode" on the desktop is doubled clicked, which changes icon to "modeOn", then when double clicking again and it won't execute the batch file, until I double click a second time. Each execution of the script requires 2 x double clicks. Looking to execute/toggle icons in the one double click like all programs.

I have tried to implement `ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache`and `cmd /C ie4uinit.exe -show` however the places I tried to put that code did not work.

Here is my BATCH file with VBScript :) I have

```
@ECHO
mode con lines=30 & color F2
IF EXIST a.txt (echo a.txt exists) ELSE (
echo Cannot find file a.txt. Visit http://www.example.com/issues and look up Issue#1. 
pause
exit
)
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%G IN (a.txt) DO @set xx=%%G
echo %xx%
IF %xx%==a (
echo a.txt reports zero therefore current config is Currently modeOff
rename "mode" "mode2"
rename "mode1" "mode"
echo mode was renamed to mode2 and mode1 was renamed to mode
@echo off
echo b > a.txt
Call:CreateShortcut "Desktop\modeshortcut" "mode" "Winver.exe,0"
pause
exit
)
IF %xx%==b (
echo a.txt reports zero therefore current config is Currently modeOn
rename "mode" "mode1"
rename "mode2" "mode"
echo mode was renamed to mode1 and mode2 was renamed to mode
@echo off
echo a > a.txt
Call:CreateShortcut "Desktop\modeshortcut" "mode" "%Windir%\System32\moricons.dll,6"
pause
exit
)
:: ======== FN ======
GOTO :EOF

:: /// check if the app has failed
::****************************************************************************************************
:CreateShortcut -c <ApplicationPath> <ShortcutName> <Icon>
(
echo Call Shortcut ("%~1","%~2","%~3"^)
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************^)
echo Sub Shortcut(ApplicationPath,Name,Icon^)
echo    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
echo    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
echo    MyTab = Split^(ApplicationPath,"\"^)
echo    If Name = "" Then
echo    Name = MyTab(UBound^(MyTab^)^)
echo    End if
echo    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
echo    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\" ^& Name ^& ".lnk"^)
echo    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote^(ApplicationPath^)
echo    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = Icon
echo    objShortCut.Save
echo End Sub
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
echo ^'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
echo Function DblQuote(Str^)
echo    DblQuote = Chr(34^) ^& Str ^& Chr^(34^)
echo End Function
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
)> Shortcutme.vbs
Start /wait Shortcutme.vbs
Del Shortcutme.vbs
::cmd /C ie4uinit.exe -show
::cmd ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache
Exit
::****************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: What did you mean by "Desktop\modeshortcut" ? location of your batch file or what ? a folder ?

Comment: not sure if understand correctly, but it sounds like software logic problem - you have to call script with param ON from your program when it works and you have to call it with param OFF when exit; you should not turn on or off status by doubleclicking - whats the point then?